# Does radiant flux depend on solid angle?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, radiometry

I learned from various sources (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux)) that the radiant flux $\Phi$ is the radiant energy emitted, reflected, transmitted, or received per unit time and is defined by:

$$\Phi(\mathbf{x},t) = {dQ \over dt}$$

where $Q$ is radiant energy, $t$ is time and $\mathbf{x}$ is a position vector in space.

From my understanding of the above equation, the radiant flux $\Phi$ **IS NOT** a function of the solid angle.  The radiant flux will add up all radiant energy in any solid angle at a given point $\mathbf{x}$ per unit time.

However, when I read more, I note from another [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity) that radiant intensity $I$ is the radiant flux emitted, reflected, transmitted or received, per unit solid angle and is defined as:

$$I={d\Phi \over d\Omega}$$

where $\Omega$ is solid angle.

From the above definition of radiant intensity, I suspect that radiant flux $\Phi$ should be a function of solid angle; otherwise, the derivative of radiant flux $\Phi$ w.r.t. solid angle $\Omega$ should always be zero.

So why radiant flux is a function of solid angle in one equation but is not in the other?  Is it due to abuse of the notation $\Phi$?

Comment: Maybe this is just semantics, but what you do really mean when you use the word 'depend'?  Ultimately a derivative doesn't imply 'dependence', at least to me.  By this logic, would a defintion for velocity v = dx/dt imply that distance x 'depends' on time t?

Comment: @SeanSkelly What I mean is whether $\Phi$ is a function of solid angle.  Updated the question.